# Deciphering this area of Indiana?

Tags: united-states, palaeography, 1830s, indiana, pension-records

I am looking at a sworn testimony for an application to transfer a Revolutionary War pension that speaks of moving before May 1838 from Aurora, Dearborn, Indiana to this location, also in Indiana:

[image: Name of town that is hard to read.]

I'm not able to figure out what it says.  I suspect it is in the County of Warrick since it appears that is where the Notary took place describing the move:

[image: Legal header for State of Indiana, probably County of Warrick]

Trying to read the town, as best as I can make it out, it reads `Yerklesburgh`, but I don't find any town with a name like that in Indiana.

Does anyone recognize the name of this town or area in Indiana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's **Sprinklesburgh** – an old name for the town that is now [Newburgh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newburgh,_Indiana), Warrick Co., Indiana.

The original name was after founder John Sprinkle. According to this [Newburgh History](http://www.newburghmuseum.com/newburgh-history/), Sprinklesburgh was united with Newburg in 1841 to form Newburgh.

Comment: That seems to agree with this transcription: http://revwarapps.org/s31800.pdf